# Show that if exists $t \in [0, 1]$ such that $L(t)=0$. Then $t=\frac{1}{2}$ and $P=-Q$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $P, Q$ two points on the sphere of radius $1$ and center at the origin. Let $L(t)=P+t(Q-P)$ with $t \in [0,1]$. Show that if exists $t \in [0,1]$ such that $L(t)=0$. Then $t=\frac{1}{2}$ and $P=-Q$

I started with this: 
Considering that $||P||=1 \wedge ||Q||=1$
If $$L(t)=0 \Rightarrow ||L(t)||^2=0$$
And 
\begin{align*}
||L(t)||^2 &= (P+t(Q-P)) \cdot (P+t(Q-P))\\
& = P^2 + 2 t [P \cdot Q - P^2] + t^2 [Q^2 -2 Q \cdot P + P^2]\\
&= 1 + 2 t [P \cdot Q - 1] + t^2 [1 -2 Q \cdot P + 1]
\end{align*}

From here I do not know how to continue developing or if my premise is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P+t(Q-P)=0$, the surely $t\neq0$ and $Q=(t-1)P/t$.  Now recall that 
$$1=\|Q\|=\|(t-1)P/t\|=|(t-1)/t|\cdot\|P\|,$$
hence $|(t-1)/t|=1$ as $\|P\|=1$ as well.

From here $t=1/2$ since $0<t<1$ and $P=-Q$.